# Excel, find the columns first and last cell entry and use that columns positions of another row

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that I have number of rows and in each row there is a string name for X number of columns.
I want to find these start column and end column and write the result into cells from same column but different row. The desire output is in start date and end date columns.

I tried to use If and counta functions, to count the length of the columns that have values and then somehow try to "go up" to the date row and write them to the start date and end date cells. Im struggling a bit how that is done in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start Date: A4: =INDEX($D$1:$M$1,MATCH(TRUE,LEN($D4:$M4)>0,0))
end date:   B4: =LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($D4:$M4)>0),$D$1:$M$1)
```

Select `A4:B4` and fill down as far as needed

[image]

*If your table might be wider, replace the column `M` designation in the formulas with a column far out enough to always include the table, even `XFD` if you want.*

Answer (score 0):

For the last cell of column D, you could use this to get the last row number:

```
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

For the first cell of column D, as you do not want to start from Row 1 (if I get it right), you could check values until non empty string starting from D2:

```
   RowIndex = 1
   Do
    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    cellValue = Range("D" & RowIndex).Value
   Loop While cellValue = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub relative_fill()
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
lr = ActiveCell.Row
lc = (ActiveCell.Column + 1)
i = 2
While i <= lr
r = -(i - 1)
Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(r, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Cells(i, lc).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(r, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(i, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```